# How to change nodes in collada files

Tags: collada, scenekit

I've created a collada file (.dae) to use in my app. I'm using Scene Kit. I have previewed the file in Xcode but I'm not able to understand how to change the properties of the nodes through code.

How can I setup something like IBOutlet to the nodes in the collada file. Do I have to create the nodes from the code so that I have reference to the visual elements in the collide file or is there anything else that I have to consider.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the "scene graph" section when previewing the Collada file in Xcode, you can see that each node has a "name" (it can also be untitled). You can also see this by selecting a node and looking in the Node inspector (<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>) when previewing the file in Xcode.

In code, you can get a reference to any one of these nodes by asking the scene's root node (or any other parent node) for a child node with a specific name, using `-childNodeWithName:recursively:`:

```
SCNNode *fooNode = [myScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Foo" recursively:YES];
```

Alternatively, you can traverse the node hierarchy via the `childNodes` and `parentNode` properties and the `-enumerateChildNodesUsingBlock:` method (all on SCNNode).